# unsupported Compose file version: X.X

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been getting the same error over and over again and can't seem to wrap my head around it o.O

> unsupported Compose file version: 3.3

...even though I've got the right compose version:

```
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
```

My docker version is:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 47e2230/1.13.1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker-compose doesn't support version files on its own, it's using docker.
your docker, however, only supports 2.2 as in 
https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-compose/#1130

It looks like you need to get more recent docker engine release first to support your desired config version

Comment: Thanks!! That was the problem.. Fixed it with: sudo dnf remove docker docker-client                docker-client-latest docker-common docker-latest docker-latest-logrotate                 docker-logrotate docker-selinux                                                                                                              then: installing the community edition: sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo     https://download.docker.com/linux/fedora/docker-ce.repo; sudo dnf install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io